# Получить ответ с сервера в виде blob или arraybuffer

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Как получить ответ с сервера в виде объекта `Blob` или `ArrayBuffer`? Делаю так

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
xhr.open("GET", "/sample.blob");
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = (e) =>  {
    console.log(e.loaded);  
    var buf = xhr.respose; 
    var reader =  new FileReader(); 
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(buf); // тут ошибка
    reader.onload = () =>  {/* ... */ };     
}
```

Выдает ошибку - `buf` не явялется объектом `blob`. Как интерпретировать ответ как двоичный файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Комменты по исправлениям в коде:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
xhr.open("GET", "/sample.blob");
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = (e) =>  {
    console.log(e.loaded);  
    var buf = xhr.response; // здесь была опечатка
} 
xhr.send(); // это в конец
```

Подробнее см. [документацию на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data).

Comment: Весьма благодарен.